# sql t-sql else if not working properly

Tags: t-sql

I have the following short version of a tsql if else if..

```
    IF @var = 1 
    BEGIN
    ... 

    END
    ELSE IF @var = 2
    BEGIN
    ....

    END
    ELSE IF @var = 3
    BEGIN
      ....
    END
    ....
```

I get a message saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN' when I use it for the @var = 2 .

not sure if I am doing something wrong

Comment: Is there anything in between the conditions? If its blank, it'll error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine, you can't have nothing between begin and end:

```
declare @var int = 2
IF @var = 1      
BEGIN     
select 1
END     
ELSE IF @var = 2     
BEGIN     
select 2
END     
ELSE IF @var = 3     
BEGIN     
select 3
END
```

Result:

```
2
```